# Matlab: Sort a dataset according to a vector

Tags: matlab, sorting, dataset

I have a dataset with multiple columns. In addition, I have a vector, which has similar data as in one column of the dataset. I need to order the whole dataset (rows) such that the column of the dataset with similar data to the vector are identical. How can I do this in Matlab? Many thanks.

Comment: Can you add a small example?

Comment: @rize When you say _dataset_, do you mean an ordinary set of values (such as a matrix) or a [_dataset object_](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/datasetclass.html) from the Statistics Toolbox?

Comment: @EitanT I mean a dataset object from Statistics Toolbox. I know the term is ambiguous, sorry for that, will be more precise in the future. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare the columns of the dataset and the vector to generate index variables. The `intersect` function provides a handy way to do this:

```
[intersection_set,iv1,id1]=intersect(vector1,dataset1(:,column_to_sort));
dataset1=dataset1(id1,:);
```

Comment: Actually what I was looking for is that I can preserve the order of the rows in the vector, and sort the matrix according to that, i.e. I use the 'stable' value for 'setOrder' parameter of intersect. Thank You!

Comment: You can do this by adding `,'stable'` after the two input arguments to `intersect` - the order of the first input will be kept stable.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
% Preparation
A = your_column_vector;
B = your_data_matrix;

C = [A; B];

% Calculation
D = sortrows(C, 1)

% Clean up
your_sorted_matrix = D(:, 2:end)
```